# Can a corporate credit card be registered to accrue points/miles?

Tags: loyalty-programs, payment-cards

I have a corporate AmEx card with my company, and travel a fair amount for work. How can I register that card for promotions/mile accrrual/etc?

Can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I presume this is a "Green" corporate Amex charge card?

The Green cards, including corporate cards, can be signed up for "Membership Rewards" which is American Expresses rewards program.

There is an annual fee payable to join Membership Rewards, but as long as you're using the card relatively frequently it'll probably be worth the fee.

Some corporates (especially if you're a government employee) have their own policies around Membership Rewards points so it would be worth checking with them to make sure that you're not breaking any of your own companies rules.

You can find more about Membership Rewards, and sign up at [www.membershiprewards.com](http://www.membershiprewards.com)

Comment: my amex is a gold one - not green

Comment: The Gold card should be exactly the same as the Green card in this respect.  The Gold card is basically the Green card with a few extra benefits, and a higher annual fee.

Comment: To clarify, not all Green cards are eligible for Membership Rewards - some companies block it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Amex Platinum then you should already be subscribed to their rewards program. Just go to the rewards tab and it'll tell you how many points you have.